# How I can list the group table with their respective group permissions and permissions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

How I can list the group table with their respective group permissions and permissions?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/F538t.png

Comment: In a view, a template, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant tables for the Auth Django contrib app, which contains users and groups and their respective permissions are named as follows in the db:

- `auth_group`
- `auth_group_permissions`
- `auth_permission`
- `auth_user`
- `auth_user_groups`
- `auth_user_user_permissions`

They can be accessed in Python with something like:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
>>> Group.objects.first().permissions.all()
```

Relevant documentation: [Django docs on contrib.auth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/)